# Echo WHOIS information of IP address through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am writing a php class which get host's WHOIS information and store them on variables to insert them into database in-case they're not already inserted and this process happens per visit, I have been using cURL to scrap information right from WHOIS website but what about server load in such situation (every connection will result an external connection, DB search and if entries not found then insert them) some people advised me to use mod_geoip2 Apache module but what if the user who's using my class is on a shared hosting which doesn't have mod_geoip2 Apache module installed, any ideas to relief the server load even for a bit ?

P.S: this not what my class generally accomplishes but this is the part where I need problem solving at!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to make intelligent use of the IP ranges returned by WHOIS.

For example, if a query of `whois aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` returns this:

```
inetnum:        aaa.bbb.ccc.96 - aaa.bbb.ccc.127
...
```

then you can store the WHOIS information for th whole range of IP adresses.

Also, to avoid querying the database over any over again, you could store the currently retrieved WHOIS information in a session variable.